# Java initialise array of annotations

Tags: java, annotations

I'm trying to initialise an array of annotations but can't figure out the syntax.

```
public @interface Tag {
    String key();
    String value();
}

@Target({ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface BaseAnnotation {

    String[] names();
    Tag[] tags();
}
```

As you can see, BaseAnnotation has an array of Tag annotation and I want to use it to annotate another annotation like this:

```
@BaseAnnotation(names={"abcs", "bnm"},
tags = {key="aaa",value="bbb"}) //I can't figure out the syntax for this one
@Target({ElementType.METHOD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface ToBeUsedAnnotation {

}
```

The problem is that I've tried a few ways to set the values for tags but can't find any useful documentation on how to do it.
Thanks.

Comment: `tags = {@Tag(key="aaa",value="bbb"), @Tag(key="bbb", value="ccc")}`

Comment: Good response, thank you